# UPDATE DATA BASE WITH JSON LIST

Tags: python, mysql, json, database

hello I have a little question

```
json_obj2=[{'coin_name': 'matic-network', 'price': 99.34}, {'coin_name': 'thorchain', 'price': 77.77}, {'coin_name': 'kyber-network', 'price': 39.18}, {'coin_name': 'pantherswap', 'price': 1.3}, {'coin_name': 'concierge-io', 'price': 5.16}]

for item in json_obj2:
    coin_name=item.get('coin_name')
    price = item.get('price')
    print(item)
```

this json_obj2 is the update for my data base what I'm trying to do so is update my date base with the new value of coin_name (not change always the same) and the price (that change every minute...) for now I try just to figure out in static ...

```
#mycursor.execute('UPDATE liste_coin SET price WHERE coin_name = matic- 
network)  VALUE (%s)',(price))
 # mycursor.execute("UPDATE liste_coin SET price WHERE coin_name='matic- 
 network') VALUE (%S)" ,(price))
 mycursor.execute("UPDATE  liste_coin  (%s, %s)", (coin_name,price))
 mydb.commit()
```

This is what I try to update my database but nothing change if someone can hel It will be very gracefull
thank you

Comment: `mycursor.execute("UPDATE liste_coin SET price=%s WHERE coin_name=%s;", (price, coin_name))`

Comment: thank you so much I'm a beginner who try to learn something in this hard time and really you save my night